# How to make a RandomForestRegressor learn to differentiatie similar inputs with different outputs?

Tags: python, regression, scikit-learn, random-forests, similarity

I'm working on a regression task with Sklearn RandomForestRegressor and I'm having some trouble distinguishing between two similar data with very different expected outputs. For example, each pair of time-stamp (x-axis) and value (y-axis) for the two blue curves shown below are different inputs for the model, and in the context of my data they are considered similar curves (and similar pair).

[image]

The expected value to be produced by the model is another value associated with the given time-stamp,as shown in the two green curves below. However, even with the two blue curves being considered similar, the expected output is very different for both.

[image]

I tried to give the full curve as input, but the generalization is compromised due to unbalances in my dataset (I mean, the result is always the same profile with small differences to each given curve). Also, all curves are normalized according to mean value (which is necessary for my research). This is just an example, but there are other cases similar to this one in the dataset.

What is happening is that my model is learning well the time-stamps with similar behavior but when there is too much difference between the points, the model is reproducing only the one that was more present in the dataset, resulting in curves that are similar for most points, but very different in other points.

I know that this is an expected behavior of learning models, but I was trying to figure out if there is anything I can do in order to minimize these difference and produce better results.